# Smoothing sensor signals with response times - how to

Tags: smoothing, moving-average, filter

I have a Sensor (e. g. for temperature) that has a response time ($t_{99}$ -> this is the time that the sensor needs to give an output of 99 % of the actual value) of let's say 10 seconds. This sensor gives me a value each second (1 Hz). The signal is noisy, but also has peaks which should not be smoothed too much.

How would you approach this problem? Is it correct to use the response time as the window size in e. g. simple moving averaging? Is it better to use a Savitzky-Golay filter for preserving the peak sizes? I would probably center the window(?) because it's all done in post processing and is not needed in realtime.
How (or is it even reasonable) can I connect the response time to my window size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it takes the sensor 10s to achieve a reliable measurement and it gives an output each second, there is probably already an internal (physical) smoothing in place. In this case, an additional smoothing would not be necessary or useful.

If the sensor gives you the raw data every second but the producer specified that a 99% reliable measurement would take 10 seconds, then you have to compute a moving average over 10s to get the correct readings. In this case, the peaks might be unreliable outliers, so it would be bad to preserve them.

If you are unsure, a little experimentation would be in order. Heat up something to a certain temperature, set up the sensor in a controllable environment and expose it to 1s, 2s, 5s, 10s of heat from this source, always giving it 30s of cooldown time after exposure. Note the exact timestamps on which you exposed it. Then, look at the data stream and adjust the post-processing (moving average, window position, peak retainment) so it matches the actual series of events best.

Comment: Thanks! It's raw data, so I probably have to take the moving average. With preserving the peaks I meant that a MA automatically flattens the whole dataset, right? Should the applied MA be centered?

Comment: Yes, MA will flatten the peaks. But if one readout is not reliable as you need 10s of measurement, they are error-prone. So, flattening is probably for the best. As for the position of the window, you have to decide (and remember) whether you want to see the onset of an increase/decrease in temperature (use last timestamp as denominator), whether you want the most reliable measurement at the current moment (use the mittle time stamp) or whether you want to identify stable phases (use first time stamp). Depending on what you need the data for, afterwards, you can pick.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! In this case I will use the centered window. Do you have any ideas for sources (books, articles?) where I can find more information about window positioning and response times?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't have any literature on this. I learned it hands-on with data streams we collected in experiments.

Comment: No problem. If you can't do any experiments how would you approach the same issue with a $t_{63}$ time for example? Would you just use trial and error with "randomly" chosen different window sizes? Or do you calculate a $t_{99}$ time and assume a specific relationship (linear, exponential, ...)?

Comment: The window length is alwas given by t63 or t99. It's a duration it takes the sensor to get the reliable reading. The t63 is just a little shorter than the t99 and less reliable. But if I can't test the solution with own experiments, I would have to rely on the manufacturer's reference and user guide. And probably call them up to ask these questions.